# How get in SQL pairs of connections in a FW Logs

Tags: vertica

I have a database with `orign_ip`, `destination_ip`, and other columns.
I am looking for a way to get in SQL just the connections between two IP's, I need to get just the list.
This is my first step :

```
SELECT DISTINCT orig_h , resp_h from gustavo.conn;
 - 15.214.135.70                15.214.159.100
 - 15.214.136.45                15.214.137.70
```

But How I can get from this result the just the rows that match with

```
15.214.135.70               15.214.159.100
```

Comment: If there was a row with `orig_h = 15.214.159.100` and `resp_h = 15.214.135.70` would you want to see that as well?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT orig_h , resp_h 
from gustavo.conn
WHERE orig_h = '15.214.135.70' AND resp_h = '15.214.159.100'`

Comment: Thank you . But in case Do I need to store the result of the first query in a temp table and do this thing for all the pairs ? One by one .

Comment: I am looking some way to collect all the connections in one query . I am looking to create some temporary table . What you think ?

Comment: @grojas123: given your sample data, this is the best answer you can get.